# put_item with a map DynamoDB boto3

Tags: python, json, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I have a json like this

```
{
  "1555430188927137": {
    "0": {
      "FORM_R_5": {
        "status": 0,
        "rating": null,
        "feedback": null
      },
      "2ABMEDIUM": {
        "status": 0,
        "rating": null,
        "feedback": null
      },
      "FORM_R_9": {
        "status": 0,
        "rating": null,
        "feedback": null
      },
      "title": "b"
    },
    "1": {
      "36ABMEDIUM": {
        "status": 0,
        "rating": null,
        "feedback": null
      },
      "35ABMEDIUM": {
        "status": 0,
        "rating": null,
        "feedback": null
      },
      "38ABEASY": {
        "status": 0,
        "rating": null,
        "feedback": null
      },
      "title": "a"
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to put this json as an map into my item but it does not seem to work I end up with this (shorten) error message :
**"serialize_to_request raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report()) botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed: Invalid type for parameter Item.packs.M.1555430188927137.M (key: 0), value: 0, type: , valid types: Invalid type for parameter Item.packs.M.1555430188927137.M (key: 1), value: 1, type: , valid types:"**

Python code

```
formation_list = {u'1555430188927137': {0: {u'FORM_R_5': {'status': 0, 'rating': None, 'feedback': None}, u'2ABMEDIUM': {'status': 0, 'rating': None, 'feedback': None}, u'FORM_R_9': {'status': 0, 'rating': None, 'feedback': None}, 'title': u'b'}, 1: {u'36ABMEDIUM': {'status': 0, 'rating': None, 'feedback': None}, u'35ABMEDIUM': {'status': 0, 'rating': None, 'feedback': None}, u'38ABEASY': {'status': 0, 'rating': None, 'feedback': None}, 'title': u'a'}}}
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='eu-west-1')
table = dynamodb.Table('MyTable')

table.put_item(
    Item={
        "id" : "test",
        "packs": formation_list
    }
)
```

It works well if I do that :

```
  Item={
        "id" : "test",
        "packs": {
            "pack" : "hello world!"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please see the following question that seems very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43538073/how-do-i-insert-a-map-into-dynamodb-table