# How do I insert a map into DynamoDB table?

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have the following line of code :

```
table.put_item( Item={'filename' : key, 'status' : {'M' : iocheckdict }})
```

The `iocheckdict` looks like this:

```
{'A': 'One', 'C': 'Three', 'D': 'Four', 'B': 'Two', 'E': 'Five'}
```

So, when I am running the code, I get this error:

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutItem operation: One or more parameter values were invalid: Type mismatch for key status expected: S actual: M
```

**Why am I getting this, even though I mentioned `M` as the type of the data?**

PS : I have 2 columns `filename` and `status` in my table

---

Attribute definitions of the table:

```
"AttributeDefinitions": [
    {
        "AttributeName": "filename",
        "AttributeType": "S"
    },
    {
        "AttributeName": "status",
        "AttributeType": "S"
    }
],
```

I understand that the type of `status` is S, but I haven't found the map type while creating the table. All I found are `string`, `binary` and `number`.

Comment: According to http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.put_item you have to pass an M, such as `"M": {"Name": {"S": "Joe"}, "Age": {"N": "35"}}`, in other words the `dict` part should be like `{"Name": {"S": "Joe"}, "Age": {"N": "35"}}`.

Comment: @EmreSevinç I have made me dictionary to `iocheckdict = {"S1": {"N": "0"}, "S2": {"N": "0"}, "S3": {"N": "0"}, "S4": {"N": "0"}, "S5": {"N": "0"}}`.  But still, this statement : `table.put_item( Item={'filename' : key, 'status' : {'M' : iocheckdict }})` gives me the same error.  Possible to write an answer?

Comment: It would be helpful if you edited your question and added detailed information about your table, e.g. the details of the schema of your table. Because I think the types of your fields `filename` and `status` might not be matching the types of your variables `key` and `iocheckdict`.

Comment: @EmreSevinç Thanks. Updated the question

Comment: A table key columns can never be anything other than number, string or binary. Also, in dynamodb creation of tables require only key columns and not other columns. A Map type of data can only be a non-key column

Comment: `Map` is available as `Document Type` in Amazon DynamoDB: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html

Comment: Thank you EmreSevinç and @omuthu. Didn't know about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43538073/how-do-i-insert-a-map-into-dynamodb-table?noredirect=1#comment74129567_43538073).  Apparently, `status` is my secondarykey. So, it's not taking map datatypes. I tried creating a new column on the fly with _put_item_ and it worked :)

Comment: yes, any columns can be there for each record. Unless your data has multiple status for a single filename key, you can go ahead with only filename as key column. See my answer below for easier way of inserting data

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easier way to insert into dynamodb

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table("table_name")

item={}
item['filename'] = key
item['status'] = {'A': 'One', 'C': 'Three', 'D': 'Four', 'B': 'Two', 'E': 'Five'}

table.put_item(Item=item)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also confused by the doc focusing on the data types.
Thanks to @omuthu's answer, I realised that one just needs to pass in the dict object. I think a slightly more succinct answer to the question is to simplify the original `put_item()` call by stripping out the 'M' (map) additional level, .i.e:

```
table.put_item( Item={'filename':key, 'status':iocheckdict} )
```

or as a working example:

```
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table("test")

key="test1235.txt"
iocheckdict = {'A': 'One', 'C': 'Three', 'D': 'Four', 'B': 'Two', 'E': 'Five'}

table.put_item( 
    Item={
        'filename': key, 
        'status':   iocheckdict 
    }
)
```